# How do I install .NET Framework 4 SDK using Ansible?

Tags: .net, ansible

Windows Server 2019, configured with Ansible.

I have tried with

```yaml
- name: Install multiple packages
  win_chocolatey:
    name:
      - nuget.commandline
      - nunit-console-runner
      - visualstudio2017buildtools
      - dotnet
      - dotnetfx
      - netfx-4.8
      - netfx-4.8-devpack
    state: present

- name: Install dotnet core SDK 1.1
  win_chocolatey:
    name: dotnetcore-sdk
    version: 1.1.14
    state: present
    allow_multiple: yes

- name: Install dotnet core SDK 2.1
  win_chocolatey:
    name: dotnetcore-sdk
    version: 2.1.510
    state: present
    allow_multiple: yes

- name: Install dotnet runtime
  win_chocolatey:
    name: dotnetcore-runtime.portable
    package_params: /ShimDotnetExe
    state: present
```

but when running `dotnet build foo.sln`, I still get:

> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.510\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1179,5):
> error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework
> ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install
> the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your
> application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK
> or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved
> from th e Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of
> reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly
> targeted for the framework you intend.

Comment: Obviously, you should install .NET 4 targeting pack

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski what is the not so obvious Chocolatey name of this mysterious ".NET 4 targeting pack"? I cannot find it on https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=.NET+4+targeting+pack

Comment: Did you read the notes from your links? _The .NET Framework 4.0 Targeting Pack needs to be installed prior to installing this package. It is included in Windows SDK v7.1 or Visual Studio 2010_ I don't think, that it's available in Chocolatey. Also, .NET 4.0 is EOL for a while, make sense to increase the version

Comment: My developers tell me that I must install this version. They have it manually installed on their TeamCity, with pointy-click next-next-next-finish. I asked and they don't know how to do it unattended. I'm attempting to recreate a fully scripted (zero human interaction) for a build node on Jenkins. I'm a Linux user since decades so I'm used to fully scripted installations, apparently this is a novel concept in the Windows world?

Comment: .NET 4, as any other version of .NET Framework, is windows only, you can't run it on Linux. Only .NET Core. But there is a `Windows Server 2019` at the top of your question and nothing prevents you to install the required SDK manually or unattended at once, then use your script

Comment: You don't understand me. I have knowledge of Linux, but I am now working on Windows. I need to install .NET Framework 4 SDK on Windows Server 2019. I am not allowed to install it manually. I must install it unattended *using the Ansible script*. Your comment is a catch-22.

Comment: What you are saying, is: "you must install foo before you can install foo". That makes no sense.

Comment: First figure out how to install this and make it work purely from powershell/chocolatey?

Comment: And *that*, my dearest @Zoredache, is exactly what my question boils down to.